# How to assert call order and parameters when mocking multiple calls to the same method?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have multiple calls to the same mock and I want to check each calls parameters and order in which it was called.

E.g. if I needed to check just the last call, I would use this:

```
mock.assert_called_once_with(
    'GET',
    'https://www.foobar.com',
    params=OrderedDict([
        ('email', 'email'),
    ]),
    headers=None, 
    data=None)
```

However I want to do this for each call.

I've managed to do that, like this:

mycode.py

```
from requests import Session

class Foo(object):

    def req(method, url, data, params=None, headers=None):
        self.session = Session()
        r = self.session.request(method, url, data=data, params=params, headers=headers)
        return r
```

test_mycode.py

```
@patch('myapp.mycode.Session')
def test_foobar(self, Session):
    # Set mock.
    self.request_mock = Session.return_value.request
    self.request_mock.return_value = MagicMock()

    data = {'foo': 'bar'}
    f = Foo()
    f.req('POST', 'https://www.foobar.com/', data=data)
    f.req('GET', 'https://www.foobar.com/', data=None)


    self.assertEqual(self.request_mock.call_count, 2)
    call1 = self.request_mock._mock_call_args_list[0]
    call2 = self.request_mock._mock_call_args_list[1]

    call_params = (
        ('POST', 'https://www.foobar.com'),
        {
            'headers': None,
            'allow_redirects': False,
            'params': None,
            'data': json.dumps(data)
        }
    )
    self.assertEqual(tuple(call1), call_params)

    call_params = (
        ('GET', 'https://www.foobar.com'),
        {
            'headers': None,
            'allow_redirects': False,
            'params': None,
            'data': None
        }
    )
    self.assertEqual(tuple(call2), call_params)
```

This works, but I'm a little concerned about my assertEqual methods on call parameters. I feel like there's a better way of doing this. I'm still fairly new to mocking so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`Mock.assert_has_calls`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_has_calls) method.

```
self.assertEqual(self.request_mock.call_count, 2)
self.request_mock.assert_has_calls([
    mock.call(
        'POST',
        'https://www.foobar.com',
        headers=None,
        allow_redirects=False,
        params=None,
        data=json.dumps(data)),
    mock.call(
        'GET',
        'https://www.foobar.com',
        headers=None,
        allow_redirects=False,
        params=None,
        data=None)
])
```

By default, `assert_has_calls` will check that the calls happen in the proper order.  If you don't care about the order, you can use the `any_order` keyword argument (set to `True`).

Comment: This doesn't work for me since apparently there are additional calls in between POST and GET. `[call('POST', 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/challenges/challenge_id', allow_redirects=False, data='{"code": "000000"}', headers=None, params=None), call().status_code.__eq__(301),
E    call().status_code.__eq__(302),
E    call().status_code.__ge__(400),
E    call().status_code.__le__(600), call('GET', 'https://api.stormpath.com/v1/challenges/challenge_id', allow_redirects=False, data=None, headers=None, params=None)],`

Comment: @BoldMarshmallow I think there are more things you need to mock in order to properly isolate what you are trying to test.

Comment: @BoldMarshmallow -- Also, you haven't actually shown your real code.  e.g. `Foo.req`  references `self` which was never defined.  There's obviously more going in (probably inside your framework) than you're showing here.

Comment: Yeah that was intentional. Sadly I can't reveal more code for privacy reasons. Ty for trying anyway.